# CordovaNetwork not beeing detected by angular controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I've a little problem with CordovaNetwork plugin on an IONIC v1.x application.

I've installed it with a

```
sudo cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-network-information
```

Injected the plugin into an angular controller

```
.controller('HomeCtrl',function($cordovaNetwork)...
```

Testing it doing

```
console.log($cordovaNetwork.isOnline());
```

And i'm getting this error:

```
$cordovaNetwork.isOnline() is not a function
```

I've already removed/installed the plugin.
The same thing with the IOS platform. 
And my cordova files include are like this:

```
<!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="lib/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.js"></script>
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>
```

What am i doing wrong?
Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what was causing the error.

I just forgot to add 'ngCordova.plugins.network' into my app.js injections.

Answer (score 1):

Place your code inside **device ready event**:

```
   document.addEventListener("deviceready", function () {

    var isOnline = $cordovaNetwork.isOnline(); 
    var isOffline = $cordovaNetwork.isOffline();

  }, false);
```